# Weird results of two performance tests

Tags: python, python-3.9

For some performance critical code, I am doing extremely basic performance tests to figure out what's slow and what's fast. Please excuse my terrible timing method, as I have basically no idea what I'm doing. Consider these two functions :

```py
>>> def testOneBillion():
    a = 0
    print(f'[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Start')
    for i in range(1_000_000_000):
        a = i
    print(f'[{datetime.datetime.now()}] End')

    
>>> testOneBillion()
[2021-04-17 17:25:19.126744] Start
[2021-04-17 17:25:33.370225] End
```

and

```py
>>> def testTenBillion():
    a = 0
    print(f'[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Start')
    for i in range(10_000_000_000):
        a = i
    print(f'[{datetime.datetime.now()}] End')

>>> testTenBillion()
[2021-04-17 17:26:10.545044] Start
[2021-04-17 17:37:01.154828] End
```

Does anyone know why  `testTenBillion` is taking **more than ten times longer** than `testOneBillion` to finish ? I would have expected linear performance scaling, and every previous range increment did behave linearly. What could be causing this ?

Comment: Wild speculation: 1bn fits into a simple 64-bit data type while 10bn requires bigint.

Comment: Python uses bignum to store integers which take 4-bytes, plus some overhead bytes (bringing this to 24 total) for numbers up to 2^30 or approximately 1 billion.  Past this, Python bignum uses extra bytes to represent numbers bringing the total number of bytes past 24.  Thus, the OneBillion function uses 24-bytes per ints, while the Ten-Billion uses more.  See [How Python Represents Integers using Bignum](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-python-represents-integers-using-bignum-f8f0574d0d6b)

Comment: @DarrylG That is extremely interesting ! Thanks a lot, the counter thankfullyhas no incidence on the real code, which doesn't use one, but this is very nice to know ! I wonder if nesting range(10) and range(1bn) would make it faster

Comment: @AmyLucyRose--yes, a double loop with range(10) and range(1bn) scales linearly (just tried it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment under your question might be correct. If I understand it correctly, Python's standard integer format can contain numbers up to 2.147483647 billion.

Source: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/ints/

EDIT: I tested the loop with 2 billion and it took only 2.1x longer than 1 billion which lends credibility to this theory.